# How to stop commands when breaking when :"overloaded"

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I have a few commands that follow this same code, just some things changed, the code is for -dog command, which works fine within moderation (not spamming the command, maybe running it every 5 seconds) but when it does get spammed it will often spit a odd error into the terminal, I was wondering if there is anyway to fix this or improve it. Thanks!

Language: Discord.js V12

````
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/lookatmydog/hot/.json?limit=100'

module.exports = {
    name: 'dog',
    description: 'sends a dog!',
    execute(message, args) {

        https.get(url, (result) => {
            var body = ''
            result.on('data', (chunk) => {
                body += chunk
            })

            result.on('end', () => {
                var response = JSON.parse(body)
                var index = response.data.children[Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1].data

                if (index.post_hint !== 'image') {

                    var text = index.selftext
                    const textembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle(subRedditName)
                        .setColor('RANDOM')
                        .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})\n\n${text}`)
                        .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`)

                    message.channel.send(textembed)
                }

                var image = index.preview.images[0].source.url.replace('&amp;', '&')
                var link = 'https://reddit.com' + index.permalink
                var subRedditName = index.subreddit_name_prefixed

                if (index.post_hint !== 'image') {
                    const textembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                        .setTitle(subRedditName)
                        .setColor('RANDOM')
                        .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})\n\n${text}`)
                        .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`)

                    message.channel.send(textembed)
                }
                console.log(image);
                const imageembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('Here is a dog, how nice!')
                    .setImage(image)
                    .setColor('RANDOM')
                    
                message.channel.send(imageembed)
            }).on('error', function (e) {
                console.log('Got an error: ', e)
            })
        })
    },
}```

The error I got writing this was:

```C:\Users\-\Desktop\Corn Flakes\commands\Fun\dog.js:26
                        .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})\n\n${text}`)
                                            ^

ReferenceError: title is not defined
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\manof\Desktop\Corn Flakes\commands\Fun\dog.js:26:45)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)```
````

Comment: Well `title` is undefined, where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: it used to come from the subreddit name, but i didnt like that so i tried changing it, would it be fixed by doing

var title = (whatever i want the title to be)?

Comment: Yes, an undefined variable can be fixed by defining it

Comment: do you know why -meme works fine without error (even when i spam) but -cat and -dog still give randoms when its spammed even when they use the exact same code? The error I get with -dog now is: 

``` var image = index.preview.images[0].source.url.replace('&amp;', '&')
                                          ^

```TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\manof\Desktop\Corn Flakes\commands\Fun\dog.js:35:43```

but im not sure how I would define this

Comment: You could try implementing a cooldown for this specific command, more info here: https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#cooldowns